# Generating SSL certificate with letsencrypt fails with "300 - Multiple Choices"

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

I've some problems getting `traefik` to generate a `lets-encrypt` certificate for a domain with the `www.` supdomain as separate SAN. I have other containers with identical configuration working in this environment.

The (debug) log is quite verbose but I was able to see this messages

```
time="2018-08-27T07:41:43Z" level=debug msg="Try to challenge certificate for domain [mydomain.de www.mydomain.de] founded in Host rule"
time="2018-08-27T07:41:43Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"mydomain.de\" \"www.mydomain.de\"]..."
time="2018-08-27T07:41:43Z" level=debug msg="Domains [\"mydomain.de\" \"www.mydomain.de\"] need ACME certificates generation for domains \"mydomain.de,www.mydomain.de\"."
time="2018-08-27T07:41:43Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [mydomain.de www.mydomain.de]..."
time="2018-08-27T07:41:56Z" level=debug msg="Unable to split host and port: address www.mydomain.de: missing port in address. Fallback to request host."
time="2018-08-27T07:42:00Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"mydomain.de,www.mydomain.de\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:mydomain.de,www.mydomain.de\" : cannot obtain certificates: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[mydomain.de] acme: Error 403 - urn:ietf:paramsacme:error:unauthorized - Invalid response from http://mydomain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/o74RJIDdodxG-hXpmX9en_55ZpptifsjYInrjY97Bic: \"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>300 Multiple Choices</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Multiple C\"\n"
time="2018-08-27T07:43:44Z" level=debug msg="No certificate provided dynamically can check the domain \"www.mydomain.de\", a per default certificate will be used."
```

The `LABEL`s used by this container are:

```
LABEL traefik.enable="true" \
      traefik.backend="mydomain-backend" \
      traefik.docker.network="web-gateway" \
      traefik.frontend.rule="Host:mydomain.de,www.mydomain.de" \
      traefik.port="80"
```

So far the message is quite obvious with `Invalid response from http://mydomain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/o74RJIDdodxG-hXpmX9en_55ZpptifsjYInrjY97Bic` which seems to return a code-300 result.
But why is this happening? Shouldnt' the traefik catch the requests to `/.well-known` and return the correct auth-key to letsencrypt? 
Using only a single domain `wwww.mydomain.de` generation of certificate works.

How can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. According to this [this blog entry](https://dev.to/c33s/lets-encrypt-certbotacmesh-and-the-300-multiple-choices-error-3e4i) it is related to the DNS settings of the first domain `mydomain.de` which has a `A`-Record pointing to my server and an `AAAA`-Record (IPv6) pointing to a different location which caused the "Multiple choice" response which is in fact a response from the certbot/letsencrypt and is not related to `traefik`.

After removing the `AAAA`-Record from DNS certificate generations now seems to work.

Comment: I don't have an AAAA record but I still get this error.